# Move files based on filename with regex and delete files with lower number in a substring in the filename

Tags: regex, windows, powershell, batch-file

I have files with the following syntax:

```
LWD_???_??????_???_??_??_LP?_??_?_*.PDF
```

Example:

```
LWD_ARC_G10000_102_UE_XX_LP5_08_E_Uebersicht_Bodenplatten
```

I want to extract substrings out of the file name and put the file into a folder with the path based on that file name like this:

```
C:\Lp5\ARC\G10\
```

First folder is the 7th part of the file name, the 2nd part is the second folder and the first 3 chars of the 3rd part is the last folder.

Then in addition to that I need an extra delete: When the files are copied to the specific folder there is a consecutively numbered part in the file name. I need the "older" files deleted so that only the "last" file is in this folder. The numbers/index is always the 30th and the 31st char.

```
LWD_FEU_L20000_005_IZ_00_LP8_XX_F.pdf      Index 00
LWD_FEU_L20000_005_IZ_00_LP8_01_F.pdf      Index 01
```

For now I only have a batch with static folders:

```
FOR /R "E:\Downloads" %%i in (LWD_ELT_A10?00_???_??_??_LP5*) do move "%%i" "C:\Lp5\ELT\A10"
FOR /R "E:\Downloads" %%i in (LWD_???_A10000_???_??_??_LP5*) do del "%%i"
...
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do that without VBS or sth. like that - only Windows Batch or PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My batch strategy is as follows:

1) get list of PDF files using DIR /B

2) parse each file name into a string consisting of (pipe delimited)

- file mask that matches name with `??` wildcard for positions 30,31
- destination path
- full file name

3) sort the strings descending, resulting in the most recent version at the top of each file name grouping.

4) process the output with FOR /F, parsing out the file mask, destination path, and full name

5) for each iteration, create the destination folder if it does not already exist, and then conditionally copy the file to the destination if there does not yet exist a file that matches the file mask.

The above strategy is non-destructive, as the original files all remain in place. You could modify step 5 to be destructive - move the newest files instead of copy, and delete the rest.

You could implement the above strategy fairly easily with pure batch. But I would use my [REPL.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) - a hybrid JScript/batch script that can efficiently perform sophisticated regular expression replacements. JREPL.BAT is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

***The following are untested***

Non-destructive version

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=|" %%A in (
  'dir /b /a-d LWD_*.PDF ^| jrepl "^(LWD_(...)_(...)..._..._.._.._(LP.)_)..(_._.*\.PDF)$" "$1??$5|c:\$4\$2\$3|$&" /i /a ^| sort /r'
) do (
  md "%%B" >nul 2>nul
  if not exist "%%B\%%A" copy "%%C" "%%B" >nul
)
```

Destructive version

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=|" %%A in (
  'dir /b /a-d LWD_*.PDF ^| jrepl "^(LWD_(...)_(...)..._..._.._.._(LP.)_)..(_._.*\.PDF)$" "$1??$5|c:\$4\$2\$3|$&" /i /a ^| sort /r'
) do (
  md "%%B" >nul 2>nul
  if not exist "%%B\%%A" (move "%%C" "%%B" >nul) else del "%%C"
)
```